# A left exact functor preserves quasi-isomorphisms between acyclic complexes

Tags: homological-algebra, derived-functors, injective-module, derived-categories

A homological algebra theorem states

> **Theorem:** Let $T: \mathscr{A} \to \mathscr{B}$ be a left exact functor between abelian categories, and let $X^\bullet \xrightarrow{f}
>  Y^\bullet$ be a quasi-isomorphism of chain complexes of $T$-acyclic
>   objects in $\mathscr{A}$. Then $T(X^\bullet) \xrightarrow{T(f)}
>  T(Y^\bullet)$ is a quasi-isomorphism.

In the proof in the book I'm reading (Iversen's *Cohomology of Sheaves*), the first line is

> Consider the mapping cone to see that it suffices to treat the case
>   where $Y^\bullet =0$.

I don't get it...can anyone give me a clue here? I'm just looking for help on this first statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any additive functor between abelian categories preserves mapping cones, and a map is a quasi-isomorphism iff its mapping cone is acyclic, or equivalently quasi-isomorphic to $0$.

Comment: Sorry, why doesn't what you said imply that any additive functor between abelian categories preserves quasi-isomorphisms?

Comment: @EricAuld No, it's only saying that it preserves quasi-isomorphisms if and only if it preserves acyclicity